# Click Event in Canvas?

Tags: android

I create the Pie Chart and Bar Chart by using Canvas.In that chart if i click or touch any of the bar i need to show the value of the Bar.How to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw a bar, you will definitely know the position of the bar in the X and Y axis. So, just add a touch listener and make it fire some event when the touch was executed in that specific area.

Comment: what if i dont know where my shape is?
for example i have candle chart and i really dont know where candles are !